Unit test a public method that does a call to a private method with static classes
so I have the following:
public void method1(int arg1,int arg2)
     method2()
    
private void method2()
     StaticClass.getConfig()

When unit testing that static getconfig fails, I am wondering what is the best approach to to test method1, is there a way to get around that nested static class?

Can you change the code? If so, the cleanest option is probably to hide the static method call behind an interface:
public class Class1
{
    private readonly IConfigProvider configProvider;
    
    public Class1(IConfigProvider configProvider)
    {
        this.configProvider = configProvider;
    }
    
    public void Method1()
    {
        this.Method2();
    }
    
    public void Method2()
    {
        this.configProvider.GetConfig();
    }
}

public interface IConfigProvider
{
    void GetConfig();
}

public class ConfigProvider : IConfigProvider
{
    public void GetConfig()
    {
        StaticClass.GetConfig();
    }
}

public class MockConfigProvider : IConfigProvider
{
    public void GetConfig()
    {
        // Do something else for unit tests.
    }
}

// When running your application:
new Class1(new ConfigProvider());

// When testing your application:
new Class1(new MockConfigProvider());

Depending on the size and complexity of your application, you may want to use a mocking framework and a dependency injection framework.
There are of course other options, but it's hard to give specific advice without knowing more about the constraints you are working with and what exactly that static method is doing.

You can use different dependency-breaking techniques desbribed on Working Effectively with Legacy Code and explained by Manuel Rivero.
For that case the best aproach is:
Replace Global Reference with Getter
● It uses Subclass & Override Method.
● To avoid the global dependencies we introduce a getter for each of them
and then apply Subclass & Override Method. Initial example
public class Inventory // a singleton...
    {
        private static Inventory? _instance;
        
        public static Inventory GetInstance()
        {
            if(_inventory == null)
            {
                _inventory = new Inventory()
            }
            return _inventory;
        }
        
        public Item GetItemForBarCode(Barcode code)
        {
            // get item with barcode from persistence
            //...
        }
    }
    
    public class RegisterSale
    {
        // more code...
        
        public void AddItem(Barcode code)
        {
            // using the Singleton!! x(
            var newItem = Inventory.GetInstance().GetItemForBarCode(code);
            _items.Add(newItem);
        }
        
        // more code...
    }

● How to do it. For each global dependency:

Use Extract Method (automatically with your IDE, or manually following
the process described in Martin Fowler’s Refactoring book) to introduce
a getter for the global dependency (snapshot).
 public class RegisterSale
 {    
     public void AddItem(Barcode code)
     {
         //!! After Extract Method
         var newItem = GetInventory().GetItemForBarCode(code);
         _items.Add(newItem);
     }

     // Extracted method. Now we can apply Subclass & Override Method here!!
     private Inventory GetInventory()
     {
         // still using the Singleton!!
         return Inventory.GetInstance();
     }
 }


Apply Subclass & Override Method. Then return a test double of the
global dependency from the overridden getter method (result).



public class RegisterSale
{
    public void AddItem(Barcode code)
    {
        var newItem = GetInventory().GetItemForBarCode(code);
        _items.Add(newItem);
    }
    protected virtual Inventory GetInventory()
    {
        return Inventory.GetInstance();
    }
}

// In some test
public class RegisterSaleTest
{
    
    [Test] 
    public void Adds_An_Item()
    {
        // some more setup code
        //...
        // we subclass & override the getter and return a test double of Inventory
        Inventory inventory = NSubstitute.Substitute.For<Inventory>();
        inventory.GetItemForBarCode(code).Returns(AnItem().withBarcode(code).Build());
        RegisterSaleForTesting registerSale = new RegisterSaleForTesting(inventory);
        
        // rest of the test...
    }
    
    public class RegisterSaleForTesting : RegisterSale
    {
        private readonly Inventory _inventory;

        public RegisterSaleForTesting(Inventory inventory)
        {
            _inventory = inventory;
        }
        
        // overriden to separate
        protected override Inventory GetInventory()
        {
            return _inventory;
        }
    }
}

